# Long strings preventing code block rendering

Tags: bug, markdown

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/353462/4177) I tried to edit the rational points given to lie in a single code block

```
(1955516573881233507049678279 : -86467145649172260650105545143411861089140 : 1),

(49225691888888099223656060329/10201 : 67749663895993353685065159554645568700902610/1030301 : 1),

(61339810590192565389735634 : -440289331793622522908840423931186017125 : 1),

(301884243790342804873202050999/1681 : 164095919303197903219089875947912899634054060/68921 : 1),

(12495717670305680867142229 : -24031745881863415519418908823242701040 : 1),

(48812081421189741670987918753619270029/14228919471376 : -3895612939954697213016286372117889003488190324193605593985/53673248632044722624 : 1),

(5561842419887590167868100830494509281/162696869449 : 9905381606012663087305509196041719017978015930195439090/65624921170340293 : 1),
```

but the last one

`(-24644413733187137559835573003063695698428162289232517969749039/810893447144357785058346728220801409 : 30847724470076383865716266151756242512110696731502256770076024073253839003102120576612459770/730206486187013450403786627354716551758061149557632577 : 1)`

won't go in, using the four-space syntax. Try it for yourself. Is there a word-length boundary that is stopping this?

Comment: Moreover, now the displayed equations that used to be line wrapped now display with a scroll bar :-/

Comment: Did you also omit the backticks around the last one? (I think that if you do so, then it works the same as the other ones.)

Comment: I wrote exactly as you would expect, no backticks, and the editing box was freaking out and wrapping onto new lines instead of adding spaces. Happy to be wrong, if you add an answer here, or edit the one I linked to.

Comment: OK, now the displayed equations are back to normal. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CW answer you can play with, with the desired input. There are four spaces on the front of the line below

```
(-24644413733187137559835573003063695698428162289232517969749039/810893447144357785058346728220801409 : 30847724470076383865716266151756242512110696731502256770076024073253839003102120576612459770/730206486187013450403786627354716551758061149557632577 : 1)
```

Comment: Feel free to rollback to the problematic version, but I think this might be what you were trying to get: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/4456/2
I have removed everything before the problematic string and then selected it and pressed Ctrl+K. If I had to guess, maybe it's the bug described here - it might have caused that when adding spaces the editor also added newlines: [Code block with more than 81 characters adds a newline if preceded with spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328450).

Comment: @Martin I think that's it.